# Textblob sentiment error after using googletrans

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate, textblob

so I want to use Textblob sentiment to calculate the sentiment of my data. But, before calculating the sentiment, I translated the data from Indonesian to English.

Here are my codes

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="utf-16")
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['english'] = df['Comment'].apply(translator.translate, src='id', dest='en')
#print(df)
#print(df['english'])
from textblob import TextBlob
def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment
    except:
        return None
    
df['sentiment']=df['english'].apply(lambda text: TextBlob(text).sentiment)
print(df['sentiment'])
```

But then I got this error

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'googletrans.models.Translated'>
```

Any Solution? By the way, the translation results were fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error occurs because you are giving something other than a string to TextBlob.
`df['english']` type is `<class 'googletrans.models.Translated'>`, so it must be changed to a string.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="utf-8")
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['english'] = df['Comment'].apply(translator.translate, src='id', dest='en')
#print(df)
#print(df['english'])
from textblob import TextBlob
def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment
    except:
        return None
df['english'] = df['english'].astype(str) #change type to string 
df['sentiment']=df['english'].apply(lambda text: TextBlob(text).sentiment)
print(df['sentiment'])
```